# How to create Json Web Token to User login in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to integrate JWT to my User login API for Authentication. How can I integrate it with my existing code that I have added below. In the code I have added a dummy token that needs to be changed accordingly. Thank you.

Adding some relevant parts of code from my django project for reference:

**Serializers**

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
token = CharField(allow_blank=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'token',
    ]
    extra_kwargs = {"password":
                        {"write_only": True}
                    }

def validate(self, data):
    user_obj = None
    username = data.get("username", None)
    password = data["password"]
    if not username:
        raise ValidationError("Kullanıcı adı gerekli.")

    user = User.objects.filter(
        Q(username=username)
        ).distinct()
    user = user.exclude(email__isnull=True).exclude(email__iexact='')
    if user.exists() and user.count() == 1:
        user = user.first()
    else:
        raise ValidationError("Böyle bir Kullanıcı Adı yoktur.")

    if user_obj:
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise ValidationError("Tekrar deneyiniz.")
    data["token"] = "asdasdasdasd"
    return data
```

**Views**

```
class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        new_data = serializer.data
        return Response(new_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^api-token-verify/', verify_jwt_token),
    url(r'^register/$', UserCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='register'),
]
```

Comment: Have you looked into this package? https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt

Comment: Yes I've already looked this package. But I dont understand exactly how can i change. If there is any example about it, please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use its in-built view `rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token` for User Login.

It creates a token.

And then you need to go to `RestrictedView` and use the token for authentication. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

More easiest way to use JWT in Python using the library called [PyJWT](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt)

**Steps:**

1. Install pip package of jwt (`$ pip install PyJWT`)
2. At the views.py:

   ```
   import jwt
   ```
3. Then goto the place, where you wanted to generate a token, 
   then use it as follows:

   ```
   encoded = jwt.encode({'email': uemail, 'phone':phone}, 'MySecretKey', algorithm='HS256')
   ```
4. Printing or adding encoded variable in the response, will give the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

First, install `pip install djangorestframework-jwt`.

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}

def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {
        "token": token,
        "user": "{}".format(user.id),
        "userid": user.id,
        "active": user.is_active
    }
    return data

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': 'jwt_response_payload_handler',
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=180),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': False,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=30),
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': 'generate_a_secret_key',
}
```

**serializers.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Token
        fields = ('key',)
```

Anywhere `authenication_classes` apply in your **views**, you'll want to add:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.authentication import JSONWebTokenAuthentication
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

***I implemented a method for Sign In with JWT and what it does is:***

1. Fetches the email and password that is send with the request and
   converts it into a string variable
2. I check if the email already
   exists in the custom user model i made.
3. If the user already
   exists, i convert the object model to dictionary so that i can get
   its particular password.
4. In that i match the password
   corresponding to user model and the password that is send with the
   post request.
5. if the email exists in the user model and the password corresponding to that user model matches the password that is sent with the post request i use the pyJWT to make the JWT with my custom data and return the response.
6. In all other cases the email and password don't match and i return "No Match"

> Suppose the request is   {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"12345" }

```
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def signin(request):

    email = list(request.data.values())[0] #gets email value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this xyz@gmail.com
    password = list(request.data.values())[1] #gets password value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this 123

    usr = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() #checks if email exists
    if usr:
      dictionary = User.objects.filter(email=email).values()[0] #converts object to dictionary for accessing data like dictionary["password"] dictionary["first_name"] etc
      if usr and dictionary["password"] == password: #check if email and its corresponing password stored matches the password that is sent
        branch = dictionary["branch"]
        id = dictionary["id"]
        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'email': email,}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        return Response({'token':encoded_jwt,'email':email,'branch':branch,'id':id})
      else: 
        return Response({'No Match'})
    return Response({'No Match'})
```

Answer (score 0):

***I implemented a method for Sign In with JWT and what it does is:***

1. Fetches the email and password that is send with the request and
   converts it into a string variable
2. I check if the email already
   exists in the custom user model i made.
3. If the user already
   exists, i convert the object model to dictionary so that i can get
   its particular password.
4. In that i match the password
   corresponding to user model and the password that is send with the
   post request.
5. if the email exists in the user model and the password corresponding to that user model matches the password that is sent with the post request i use the pyJWT to make the JWT with my custom data and return the response.
6. In all other cases the email and password don't match and i return "No Match"

> Suppose the request is   {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"12345" }

***views.py***

```
    @api_view(['POST'])
    def signin(request):

    email = list(request.data.values())[0] #gets email value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this xyz@gmail.com
    password = list(request.data.values())[1] #gets password value from post request {"email":"xyz@gmail.com", "password":"123"} -> this 123

    usr = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() #checks if email exists
    if usr:
      dictionary = User.objects.filter(email=email).values()[0] #converts object to dictionary for accessing data like dictionary["password"] dictionary["first_name"] etc
      if usr and dictionary["password"] == password: #check if email and its corresponing password stored matches the password that is sent
        branch = dictionary["branch"]
        id = dictionary["id"]
        encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({'email': email,}, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        return Response({'token':encoded_jwt,'email':email,'branch':branch,'id':id})
      else: 
        return Response({'No Match'})
    return Response({'No Match'})
```