# How to properly build json web token in python

Tags: python, django

Am trying to build Json web token in python django using
[pyjwt library](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) by referencing suggestion by **Madhu_Kiran_K** from stackoverflow
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635092/how-to-create-json-web-token-to-user-login-in-django-rest-framework)

In the code below, Am trying Generates a JSON Web Token that stores this user's ID, email and has an expiry date set to 2 days into the future.
I can succesfully encode and decode the token to get all the required users information and token expiration time.

**My Requirement Now:**

1.)Please how do  I validate and ensure that the token sent by client is still valid and hence not tampered.

2.)how to check for expiration time and print a message.
Here is what I have done to that effect

```
#check if the token were tampered

if content['user_id'] =='' or content['email'] == '':
    print("Invalid Token")
else:
    print("Token is still valid")

#check if token has expired after 2 days

    if content['exp'] > dt:
        print("Token is still active")
    else:
        print("Token expired. Get new one")
```

The time expiration checking returns **error message not supported between instances of int and datetime.datetime.** What is the proper way to validate. Thanks

**below is the full code**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re
import json

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import jwt


#https://www.guru99.com/date-time-and-datetime-classes-in-python.html
#timedelta(days=365, hours=8, minutes=15)
#'exp': int(dt.strftime('%s'))


dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=2)           
encoded_token = jwt.encode({'user_id': "abc", 'email': "nancy@gmail.com", 'exp': dt }, 'MySECRET goes here', algorithm='HS256')
print(encoded_token)

#decode above token
decode_token=jwt.decode(encoded_token, 'MySECRET goes here', algorithms=['HS256'])

content = decode_token
print(content)
print(content['user_id'])
print('json token successfully retrieved')

if content['user_id'] =='' or content['email'] == '':
    print("Invalid Token")
else:
    print("Token is still valid")

#check if token has expired after 2 days

    if content['exp'] > dt:
        print("Token is still active")
    else:
        print("Token expired. Get new one")
```

Comment: To ensure there's no tampering, you could use a secured hashing algorithm such as SHA-256. To check the time, you wouldn't want to use `dt` as when you restart your script `dt` would be in the future, ideally you would want to use `dt` to build the json object, but checking it should rely on today's date. Just a few thoughts maybe to guide you in the right direction

Comment: For checking if the token is valid, shouldn't you be comparing the current token to the token originally given to a user? I don't think I can help, I just think your question is an interesting one.

Comment: @MooingRawr: not sure what you are saying about `dt` there, but it doesn't seem to make much sense. `jwt.encode()` supports an `exp` expiry date in the input dictionary, which is checked *for you* when decoding again.

Comment: @Reez0: there isn't any need to check the token manually, as the digital signature is used for that instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to manually check the token validity or the `exp` deadline, the `jwt.decode()` function validates *both for you*.

For example, `jwt.decode()` will raise an [`jwt.ExpiredSignatureError` exception](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError) if the token is too old, so just catch that explicitly:

```
try:
    decode_token = jwt.decode(encoded_token, 'MySECRET goes here', algorithms=['HS256'])
    print("Token is still valid and active")
except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
    print("Token expired. Get new one")
except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
    print("Invalid Token")
```

The [`jwt.InvalidTokenError` exception](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jwt.exceptions.InvalidTokenError) is the base exception, catching that covers all the possible ways that token validation can fail. If you want to catch any subclasses such as `jwt.ExpiredSignatureError`, put them in `except ...:` blocks before catching `InvalidTokenError`.

See the [usage examples documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), especially the [*Expiration Time Claim* section](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#expiration-time-claim-exp):

> Expiration time is automatically verified in `jwt.decode()` and raises `jwt.ExpiredSignatureError` if the expiration time is in the past[.]

Comment: Thanks Sir Martin Pieters, I appreciate your solution as the best.
Now lets consider two scenario

1.) I have a requirements to force every user to get new token eg after every 4 hours, or 8 hours, or every 2 days etc. In this case do I have to wait for PYJWT
to timeout token as being too old. what if it takes PYJWT eternity to timeout.

2.) According to what i read somewhere in stackoverflow, I was meant to understand that whenever token is tampered, either of the userid or email will be empty.
Is the approach not applicable with PYJWT

Comment: @NancyMooree: the user is given a fixed token, with a timestamp embedded in it. The digital signature ensures that they can't alter the token, they can only give you the original token and nothing else. It doesn't matter how long it takes before they give that token back to your server, either the token is valid (the signature checks out and the `exp` value is still in the future), or it isn't. You don't have to worry about that, its the job of `jwt.decode()` to worry about validation and checking the `exp` expiration.

Comment: Thanks I now understand.  all your links were useful. Thanks

Comment: @NancyMooree: I'd love to see where you read about token tampering. The whole point of JWT is that you are not able to tamper with the token, it has been signed digitally. There have been [problems with JWT security in the past](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/vulnerabilities), but if you configure the valid, acceptable algorithms on decoding, then you can trust the signature. You already do that with `algorithms=['HS256'])`.